# Why is an empty Unity Iphone Build over 700 Megs? Is this Normal?

Tags: unity, iphone, xcode

So after 2 weeks of slaving over my first game I was finally done! I was entirely ecstatic....until I saw its file size.

770 Megabytes

For a simple numbers game, that was way too much and I created an empty unity project as a test and that was also over 700 megs

Why is an empty Iphone project this large?

Comment: Related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119439/reducing-mobile-build-size https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129781/will-importing-more-items-from-unity-packages-increase-the-build-size https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html

Comment: [What does your build log tell you](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) about what's taking up the file size? Note that mobile builds sometimes bundle together versions for multiple different phone models for an app store submission, where the store handles distributing just the right version for a given player's phone out of that collection, along with additional info that's just for internal use. So the file size that a player downloads may be substantially smaller than the file size you upload. Always test to confirm.

Comment: The build log reports:                                                                                            
Textures               3.9 mb  37.2% 
Meshes                 0.0 kb          0.0% 
Animations             52.4 kb  0.5% 
Sounds                 59.0 kb  0.5% 
Shaders                183.8 kb  1.7% 
Other Assets           2.0 mb  18.8% 
Levels                 74.0 kb  0.7% 
Scripts                469.6 kb  4.3% 
Included DLLs          3.8 mb  36.0% 
File headers           24.9 kb  0.2% 
Total User Assets      10.6 mb  100.0% 
Complete build size    659.3 mb

Comment: Are you making a development build with all of the debug settings enabled? This can increase your build size a lot as the build will include debug symbols etc. Also, make sure you are using the latest version of the Unity branch you're using in case it's an engine bug.